# How to unlock a SPFile.SPCheckedOutStatus.ShortTerm lock on a ListItem on both Sharepoint 2007 and 2010

Tags: check-out, spfile

How can a site administrator remove a short term lock on a SPListItem.SPFile object? This happens when a user opens a Office document for editing from a list without doing a checkout. If the user does not close the document an administrator cannot remove the shortterm lock.

At the moment, i want unlock that SPFile. Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

MS recommends waiting 10 mins or rebooting the server. 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/899709/en-us

Sometimes (mostly) that won't work so try out this code.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/93965/Force-SharePoint-Document-Unlocked-Checked-In